# Attribute background-image not work when export ios app ionic-v2

Tags: ionic2

I set backround-image like this

```
 background-image: url('/assets/img/Layer2.png');
```

It work on Browser but not work on ios divice . thanks for reading my questions

Comment: Are the assets copied to the iOS folder? `'/platforms/ios/assets/www/assets/'`

Answer (score 0):

You must be trying to set image in an scss file. You got the relative path incorrect.

The path is:

```
 background-image: url('../assets/img/Layer2.png');
```

*If* you are setting in html file it is ./assets/img/Layer2.png